# Use in repairing wires

Tags: electrical

Can these connectors be used for a splice inside of a wall in order to fix a damaged wire? If you have a damaged wire inside a wall - not a box - will these type connectors meet code as a permanent splice to fix the wire in the wall?

Comment: What type of connectors are you talking about, pray tell?  ;-)

Comment: Hi Terry. If you ever return to this post, please update it with the information asked for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You don't seem to have identified the type of connector you are asking about.

There **are** rated and approved splice kits suitable for splicing NM cable inside the wall without a junction box.

For example, look at this one: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Tyco-Electronics-Romex-Splice-Kit-2-Wire-1-Clam-CPGI-1116377-2/202204326.

Note the strain relief on both sides of the splice, and the enclosed nature of the connection. But the real point is that it is legally approved for this use.

[image]

Comment: Uprated for showing me something new... thanks!